# How can i programmatically generate descriptors for an arbitrary data set?

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network, pca

I am currently analyzing a set of pictures, that I want to classify. 
Classification is done by a Artificial Neural Network in a supervised manner. 
I have a test set that assigns to a each picture its class.

What I want to do now is generate a lot of descriptors and then do a PCA on these 
and do a statistical analysis how much the descriptor is able to describe the 
class of the picture.

How can i generate descriptors for these pictures programatically? This could help me in future classification problems too. Let us assume I have enough computation power (100 core cluster)
Are there libraries that incorporate a lot of descriptors for images?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can basically follow two approaches to start:

- Feature based, using methods such as [SIFT](http://vlfeat.org) or [GIST](http://people.csail.mit.edu/torralba/code/spatialenvelope/) followed by the so called *Bag of Words* approach. The vlfeat site contains an excellent demo of this.
- Deploying [deeplearning](http://deeplearning.net/) algorithms, such as the [Sparse Autoencoder](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/UFLDL_Tutorial) to learn basic features of your dataset which can then be further used for classification.

Comment: this is quite helpful. I would add a bounty, if i could get a working python example for this. I would like to train images of the screen onto keys pressed. could you see this working?

Comment: Yes I could potentially, and vlfeat has python wrappers